# Replace existing DATE format with another format in SSRS expression

Tags: sql, regex, date, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I have a table which has a **TEST** column which contains many values:

**TEST**

```
2014-04-02
2014-04-03
2014-04-04
WEEKLY TOTAL
PRIOR WEEK
12 WEEK
```

How can I write an expression using `IIF` statement so if the row contains a date then change the date to a different format?

For example:

The first row has `2014-04-02` (yyyy-mm-dd) which should be changed to `02-Apr` (dd-mmm)
The last row has `12 week` which should not be touched because it's not a date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

```
=iif(isDate(Fields!Test.Value)
     ,FORMAT(
            CDATE(iif(isDate(Fields!Test.Value), Fields!Test.Value, Nothing))
           , "dd-MMM"
           ) 
   ,Fields!Test.Value)
```

**Solution 2:**
Handle it in SQL itself using `CASE WHEN`

Comment: Did the job. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

IF all of your dates have a '-' AND none of your text has a '-':

```
=IIF(Fields!TEST.Value like "*-*", FORMAT(CDATE(Fields!TEST.Value), "dd-MMM")  ,Fields!TEST.value)
```

Not tested, but should work. Edited to return an actual date.

Edit: after some more experimentation, it dawned on me that what you want would result in the SSRS column having an inconsistent type (date/string), and I don't think it is possible to have both string types and date types in the same column.

My mistake was not to realize this sooner.

In order to return actual dates, you will need to clean/filter your data.

Comment: Thanks. It's working so far except, the `dd-mmm` needs to be a date not just string. :/

Comment: Ah, I missed that part.

Comment: The issues that are being displayed is, the date row is showing `02-00` and the last three rows is displaying `#ERROR`

Comment: The first issue is that the Format clause should really be "dd-MMM" instead of dd-"mmm", which I have corrected.

Comment: Thanks that solved the first part. Still getting an error for the last three row :/

Comment: The issue is that the IIF does not short-circuit.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915970/display-blank-value-as-date-in-ssrs
and
http://www.sqlsafety.com/?p=321
deal with the issue, but I can't get them to work and will not be able to devote serious time to it for an hour or so.